# mousedown event sometimes squelched on jquery draggable element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

If I left-click on a jquery draggable element, the mousedown event never reaches my custom handlers.  However, if I left-click, the mousedown event DOES reach my other handlers.  Any idea as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you give some example code? When you say, "sometimes," does this mean it also works on other occasions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because jQuery is stopping propagation of the event to prevent bugs that happen because of it.  One reason is so it doesn't drag multiple draggable items at once in IE.

Comment: that is a problem as I have other event handlers for mousedown events on the same element that need to receive the event.  How can I prevent jquery from stopping propagation of mousedown or work around this?  I noticed it only seems to happen when I bind event handlers to "dragstart" or "drag" events.

Comment: Actually I have other handlers on a different element.

Comment: I just looked into this some more and I believe this is a defect in jquery.event.drag.  Stopping propagation in this plug-in prevents live() bound event handlers attached to draggable elements from receiving the mousedown events.

Comment: That could totally be it.  I would make a sandbox page and experiment with just those elements.  Maybe changing live to click?  Might have to dive into the jquery source to see what's going on.

Comment: I found a way to work around it.  The problem was that I was binding to mousedown events using delegate w/ a context/parent element that existed above the draggable container.  Because live binding requires the event bubble up to the parent/context element before the elements represented by the selector are notified, I never received the mousedown because the mousedown event propagation was stopped at the draggable container, which is one element below the context I used for live binding.  I changed my mousedown live binding statement to use the draggable container element as context instead.

Comment: I'm running into other issues due to the fact that the jquery-event-drag plugin squelches mousedown, though.  This really was a poor design decision on the part of the plugin developer, in my opinion.  At the very least, there should be some option to prevent the plugin from preventing propagation of such a widely used DOM event.

Comment: I was able to work around those as well, but there definitely needs to be some thought put into addressing this return false at the end of the init function in jquery.event.drag.js.  I should note that this only comes into play when you attempt to bind an event handler to drag or dragstart.